# Failure to install psutil on windows

Tags: python, installation, psutil

I am trying to install psutil on windows 10 for python 3.4

I have done pip install psutil, however was met with a bunch of errors.

I'm sorry I tried to copy console error messages however it would not let me, I hope that this will be sufficient for someone to help and see what my problem is.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ART9d.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLuSb.png

I have actually found other people with the same problem as I have, however the solution given to them is sudo, and this of course does not apply to me.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

pip is failing as psutil needs Microsoft Visual C++
if you have anaconda, try `conda install psutil`

Comment: I installed the visual studio requirement as shown through console www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279 however I still get the error message after installing??

Comment: did you tried my approach? Installing through conda

Answer (score 0):

Same kind of error occurs when you try to install psutil for Python 3.9, see https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1865.

This dependency to Visual C++ was removed in version 5.8.0 of psutil, see https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1850

So one solution is to upgrade to psutil 5.8.0, if you use python version equal or greater than 3.6